# Inclusion of column spaces of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a finite principal ideal ring, $L \in M_{m \times n}(R) \setminus \{0\}, L^\prime\in M_{m \times n}(R), \alpha: \operatorname{Mat}_{m \times n}(R) \rightarrow M_{n \times m}(R)$ a linear isomorphism (so $\alpha(L)\neq 0$). Suppose $L^\prime P \alpha(L)=-LP\alpha(L^\prime)$, for all $P \in \operatorname{GL}_n(R)$. Show that $\operatorname{colsp}(L^\prime) \subset \operatorname{colsp}(L)$.

I have a hint that we can use the following lemma to prove this, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Lemma: Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and $C$ a nonzero $m \times n$ matrix over $R$. Show $\sum_{P \in \operatorname{GL}_m(R)}\operatorname{Im}PC=R^m$, where $\operatorname{Im}$ denotes the column space.

Comment: Have you tried to use the lemma in the LHS (with $n$ and $m$ exchanged)? There we can get any matrix of form $L' M$, $M\in M_{n \times m}$ arbitrary. The columns of these matrices are exactly the elements of $\text{colsp} L'$ — why?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist So you're saying I should write $L^\prime \sum_{P \in \operatorname{GL}_n(R)} \operatorname{Im} P \alpha(L)=L^\prime R^n = \operatorname{colsp}L^\prime$, right? I think I don't fully get it yet, sadly

Comment: What does remain unclear: the equality you wrote in the comment, or how to proceed?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I understand the equality I wrote, but I don't quite see how to proceed

Comment: The columns of the matrices on the RHS are from $\text{colsp} L$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist thank you!